# How to skip a field and only unmarshal a specific member of that field using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

I need to unmarshal an XML file for which I have created a model. in the XML file, I have an element name which in my model is a member of a field of type Person.
 what I want to do is to unmarshal "name" element into person.name but the problem is that in the XML file there is no node for Person and it right goes to "name". Is it possible to achieve this via JAXB?

This is a simplified version of the XML file:

```
<root>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Jack</name>
</root>
```

And these are the models I'm trying to unmarshal the XML into:

```
@XmlRootElement (name = "root")
public class Container{
    @XmlElement
    int id;

    //how should I annotate this?
    Person person;
}
public class Person{
    int age;

    //and how should I annotate this one?
    String name;
}
```

what i expect to happen:
I have a container for which `container.person.name.equals("Jack") && container.id == 1`

I tried to set the XmlElement in `person` and `Person.name` (tried all the combinations) to no avail.

The point of using this approach (not including the person in XML) is that this "name" in my real code is an expression which I need to process and assign values to different fields of person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this specific mapping, add a `name` getter and annotate it with `@XmlElement`.
The idea is using `name` getter and setter defined in `Container` to allow JAXB  rely on the `Person` field as it marshals or unmarshals the `root` element.

To allow only unmarshalling :

```
@XmlElement
public void setName(String name) {
    if (person == null){
       person = new Person();
    }
    person.setName(name);
}
```

To allow both marshalling and unmarshalling :

```
@XmlElement
public String getName() {
     return person.getName();
}

public void setName(String name) {
    if (person == null){
       person = new Person();
    }
    person.setName(name);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. although this way it adds many extra fields and setter getters to the model I don't think there would be any other simpler workaround for this. I decided to name such fields "dummy_xxx" just to distinguish between them and other model fields.

Comment: You are welcome :) Normally you would not need to add extra fields, only setter and getter.

Comment: You're right! Just one more question if you don't mind. What is the purpose of the getter? I only used a setter without any getter and the unmarshaling worked just fine.

Comment: Sure. It works fine because you don't marshal to xml. Setter is using for unmarshalling (xml->java) and getter for marshalling (java->xml). I added both to handle both cases but if you don't need to marshal, yes remove it. I updated to specify cases.